# Negate part of pattern using sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed, regex-negation, regex-group

I want to create a pattern that will find the first string that matches the pattern and replaces it:

```
sed -r '0,/^[a-z0-9]* (ALL=\(ALL\) ALL)/s//abc \1\n&/'
```

My input is an `/etc/sudoers` file.

I would like to change `^[a-z0-9]*` to something like `/^ALL/!` but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: If you are still busy with it, please clarify: do you want to skip (avoid matching) `abcALL ALL=(ALL) ALL` or `abc ALL=(ALL) ALL ...ALL...`? Or both?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you like to remove `abc` from your string, which this expression might help you to do so:

```
([^abc]*)(.*)
```

[image]

```
#!/bin/bash
STRING="(ALL=(ALL) ALL)/s//abc"
MATCH="$(sed 's/\([^abc]*\)\(.*\)/\1/' <<< $STRING)"
echo $MATCH
```

#### Output

```
(ALL=(ALL) ALL)/s//
```

#### RegEx

If this wasn't your desired expression, you can modify/change your expressions in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Cd8ZZM/1).

#### RegEx Circuit

You can also visualize your expressions in [jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]

Comment: No, I would like to make regex that matches `<string> ALL=(ALL) ALL` where string can be everything, but not 'ALL'.

Answer (score 1):

**Replacing First Occurrence in File**

If I understand your question and you want to find the first string within the file that matches `^[a-z0-9]+ ALL=(ALL) ALL` and replace the `^[a-z0-9]+ ALL` with something like `^ABC` using *Extended regex*, you can use:

```
sed -r '0,/[a-z0-9]+/s/^[a-z0-9]+ ALL(=\(ALL\) ALL.*$)/^ABC\1/'
```

Looking at the uncommented lines in an `/etc/sudoers` with `sudo` access provided to members of the `wheel` group, you would have:

```
$ noc /etc/sudoers
root ALL=(ALL) ALL
%wheel ALL=(ALL) ALL
%wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

So to replace the first string with `[a-z0-9]+ ALL=(ALL) ALL` in `/etc/sudoers` with `^ABC=(ALL) ALL`, you would:

```
$ noc /etc/sudoers | sed -r '0,/[a-z0-9]+/s/^[a-z0-9]+ ALL(=\(ALL\) ALL.*$)/^ABC\1/'
^ABC=(ALL) ALL
%wheel ALL=(ALL) ALL
%wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

**Edit Per-Comment**

In your comment you say you want to find "`<string> ALL=(ALL) ALL` where `string` can be everything, but not `'ALL'`". Since `sed` doesn't support look-ahead or look-around, about the best you can do is to explicitly not match `ALL` at the beginning of the line. Meaning you want to find lines beginning `^[^A][^L][^L]`. While that is somewhat restrictive in it will look for line that do not begin with `"ALL"`, that may be your only recourse. Like:

```
sed -r '0,/^[^A][^L][^L]/s/^[^A][^L][^L][^ ]+( ALL=\(ALL\) ALL.*$)/^ABC\1/'
```

Take the `sudoers` file example again and include `ALL ALL=(ALL) ALL` that you do not want to match, e.g.

```
$ cat sudoers
ALL ALL=(ALL) ALL
root ALL=(ALL) ALL
%wheel ALL=(ALL) ALL
%wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Now apply the expression locating the first `<string>` not `ALL` in `<string> ALL=(ALL) ALL` and you get:

```
$ sed -r '0,/^[^A][^L][^L]/s/^[^A][^L][^L][^ ]+( ALL=\(ALL\) ALL.*$)/^ABC\1/' sudoers
ALL ALL=(ALL) ALL
^ABC ALL=(ALL) ALL
%wheel ALL=(ALL) ALL
%wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

---

**Replace Numbered Occurrence within Line**

If you want to replace the occurrence within a line. With extended regex, using `s/find/replace/n` where `n=1,2,3..` is the occurrence of the `find` pattern to replace, you can replace the first occurrence with, e.g.

```
sed -r 's/[0-9a-z]+/cde456/1'
```

For example:

```
$ echo "abc123---abc123---abc123" | sed -r 's/[0-9a-z]+/cde456/1'
cde456---abc123---abc123
```

Or to replace the second occurrence, you would use:

```
$ echo "abc123---abc123---abc123" | sed -r 's/[0-9a-z]+/cde456/2'
abc123---cde456---abc123
```

The same occurrence matching is available with basic regular expressions, you simply do not have the `'+'` (match one or more occurrences) available, do you must alter your `find` pattern, e.g.

```
sed 's/[0-9a-z][0-9a-z]*/cde456/1`
```

to replace the wanted occurrence without using extended regex.

Comment: I would like to make regex that matches <string> ALL=(ALL) ALL where string can be everything, but not 'ALL'.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to avoid matching the first occurrence of a pattern if `ALL` is present in the part before the `ALL=(ALL) ALL` substring.

Use

```
sed -i '/^.*ALL.* ALL=(ALL) ALL/b;s/^.* \(ALL=(ALL) ALL\)/abc \1\n&/;T;:a;n;ba' file
```

If you have no GNU `sed` you may try

```
sed -i '' -e '/^.*ALL.* ALL=(ALL) ALL/b' -e 's/^.* \(ALL=(ALL) ALL\)/abc \1\n&/' -e ':a;n;ba' file
```

**NOTES**

- `/^.*ALL.* ALL=(ALL) ALL/b;` - finds the line having `ALL` before `ALL=(ALL) ALL` and stops processing that line
- `s/^.* \(ALL=(ALL) ALL\)/abc \1\n&/` performs the replacement (note `.*` will match any 0 or more chars as many as possible)
- `T` - if not successful, end processing that line
- `:a;n;ba` - a loop that makes sed simply read and print the rest of the lines to the end of the file.